# WinUI 3 fill width/height

Tags: xaml, winui-3

So I'm trying a simple chat application in which I have some tabs on the top and each tab should have a RichTextBlock for output, a ListView at the right of the RichTextBlock for info and a RichTextBox for input. This is all contained in a Page to be displayed under a NavigationView.

I want the chat output to take full width of the window and most of the height, and the chat input to take full width and the remaining of the height.

Now matter what I 'm trying, I can't make the sizes work.

Results: The row heights in the grid are ignored. The RichTextBlock only grows in height where there's text in it (while I want it full height even without text), and the chat input width isn't expanded.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template_Tab" x:DataType="local:Item">
    <TabViewItem  HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource Template_TabHeader}" IsClosable="True" CloseRequested="Close_Requested" >
        <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="12*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <SplitView x:Name="splitView" Grid.Row="0"
                           IsPaneOpen="{x:Bind IsOpenChannels}" OpenPaneLength="256" DisplayMode="Inline" PanePlacement="Right">
                <SplitView.Pane>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <InfoBar Grid.Row="0" IsOpen="True" Severity="Informational" Title="" CloseButtonClick="Cmd_CloseList"/>
                        <ListView  Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Channels,Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="List_Channels"  SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template_Channel}" 
                                   RightTapped="Channels_RightTap" DoubleTapped="Channels_DoubleTap"
                                   />
                    </Grid>
                </SplitView.Pane>

                <ScrollViewer Name="Scroll"
                      Margin="0"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <RichTextBlock x:Name="Output" Margin="0,0,0,10" IsColorFontEnabled="True" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="True" IsTextSelectionEnabled="True" >
                    </RichTextBlock>
                </ScrollViewer>

            </SplitView>


            <Line Stroke="SteelBlue" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="LineSep1"
                      X1="0" Y1="0"
                      X2="{x:Bind ChatWidth}" Y2="0"
                      Margin="0,10,0,10"
                      StrokeThickness="3"/>

            <StackPanel x:Name="InputSP" Margin="0,10,10,0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" MaxHeight="70" >
                <Button x:Name="ib1" >
                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE713;" />
                    <Button.Flyout>
                        <MenuFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Reset"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
                            <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Repeat" IsChecked="True"/>
                            <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Shuffle" IsChecked="True"/>
                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </Button.Flyout>
                </Button>
                <RichEditBox x:Name="Input"  KeyDown="KD"  AcceptsReturn="False"></RichEditBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </TabViewItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

Basically, my question is how to use the Grid to force width and height of elements fully in the contained Page.

In plain Win32 of course I would handle WM_SIZE, take the rect of the window with GetClientRect and adjust each control's position with SetWindowPos.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

First, make sure your `TabView`'s `VerticalAlignment` is set to `Stretch`.

Then, adjust the `RowDefinitions` on the root `Grid` of the `TabViewItem`. You are assigning too much space for the "Line" and the "Input" section.

```xml
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

This way, the 2nd and 3rd rows will take the minimum height, and the 1st row, which is the "Output" row, will take the rest.

You should also try setting each `ScrollViewer`'s `[Horizontal/Vertical](Content)Aligment` to `Stretch`.

Comment: I pasted your code on a blank WinUI 3 app and at least the `ScrollViewer` is stretched. Since the `RichTextBlock` doesn't have `Background` or `Border`s, I guess that should do.